# trim the data after special character and concatenate row data into column with comma delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle

Trim data after special character and concatenate row data into column with comma delimiter

Current data format:

```
INDIA-001 UNIT1-RUNNING
AUSTRIA-002 UNIT2-RUNNING
CHINA-003 UNIT1-RUNNING
JAPAN-004 UNIT2-ONHOLD.,
```

Expected output:

```
INDIA,AUSTRIA,CHINA,JAPAN
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `LISTAGG()` here along with a substring operation:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(SUBSTR(data, 1, INSTR(data, '-') - 1), ',')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(data, INSTR(data, '-') + 1, 3))) countries
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: current output: abc-123 abc., bcd -234 xejc, efg- xejc123.,
expected output: abc,bcd,efg

I want to trim the data  after '-' till comma
Please suggest on the same

Comment: My query along with your sample data should _not_ be generating this output.  Check your data.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a regex function as

```
SELECT LISTAGG(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'[^-]+'), ',') AS countries
  FROM t
```

if sorting based on the those zero lpadded values(`001`,`002`..) matters, then use

```
SELECT LISTAGG(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'[^-]+'), ',') AS countries
        WITHIN GROUP 
        (ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'[^- ]+',1,2))) AS countries
  FROM t
```

Note that the `WITHIN GROUP` clause is optional, and only needed whenever sorting is needed, for the versions starting from `19c`

**Edit** : If your data is seperated by line feed character conforming to the display in the question, then you can use

```
 SELECT LISTAGG( REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'[^'||CHR(10)||']+',1,level) ,'[^-]+'), ',' )
         WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'[^- ]+',1,2)) ) AS countries
   FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(col,CHR(10))+1
```

Comment: Current data : INDIA-001 UNIT1-RUNNING , AUSTRIA-002 UNIT2-RUNNING, CHINA-003 UNIT1-RUNNING, JAPAN-004 UNIT2-ONHOLD.,
above query gives output like : INDIA alone but I want output like INDIA,AUSTRIA,CHINA,JAPAN.
Please help me on the same

Comment: Hi @ShriNivi , firstly I presumed those lines within the question to be the independent data spreaded on each row. Considering this data above, is this comma separated only or  some carriage return or line feed separated ?

Answer (score 0):

You could cut off everything from first '-' with REPLACE() function and use the LISTAGG() analytic function to create a list. Notice that there is a 4000 characters limit for a column.
This is for data in four rows:

```
WITH         -- Sample data
    tbl AS
      (
          Select 1 "ID", 'INDIA-001 UNIT1-RUNNING' "TXT" From Dual Union All
          Select 2,      'AUSTRIA-002 UNIT2-RUNNING'     From Dual Union All
          Select 3,      'CHINA-003 UNIT1-RUNNING'       From Dual Union All
          Select 4,      'JAPAN-004 UNIT2-ONHOLD'        From Dual 
      )
--
--  SQL
Select      LISTAGG(REPLACE(TXT, SubStr(TXT, InStr(TXT, '-')), ''), ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By ID) "TXT"
From        tbl
--
--  R e s u l t:
TXT                         
----------------------------
INDIA,AUSTRIA,CHINA,JAPAN
```

Below - if the data is in a single row/column without line feeds:

```sql
WITH 
    tbl AS
      (
          Select 1 "ID", 'INDIA-001 UNIT1-RUNNING AUSTRIA-002 UNIT2-RUNNING CHINA-003 UNIT1-RUNNING JAPAN-004 UNIT2-ONHOLD.,'  "TXT"  From Dual 
      )
SELECT LISTAGG(SubStr(TXT, 1, CASE WHEN InStr(TXT, '-') - 1 = -1 THEN 9999999 ELSE InStr(TXT, '-') - 1 END), ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By 1) "TXT"
FROM  (   Select      l.LVL, 
                      LTRIM(REPLACE(SubStr( t.TXT, 
                                            CASE WHEN l.LVL = 1 THEN 1 ELSE Instr(t.TXT, ' ', 1, (LVL-1)*2) END, 
                                            CASE WHEN l.LVL = 1 THEN Instr(t.TXT, '-', 1, 1) - 1 ELSE 9999999999 END
                                          ), ''))  "TXT"
          From        tbl t
          Inner Join  (  Select LEVEL "LVL" From Dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CEIL((Select Length(TXT) - Length(Replace(TXT, ' ', '')) "LN" From tbl)/2)  ) l ON(1 = 1) 
      )
```

And if there are some line feed characters, tabs and spaces:

```sql
WITH 
    tbl AS
      (
          Select 1 "ID", 'INDIA-001 UNIT1-RUNNING 
                          AUSTRIA-002 UNIT2-RUNNING 
                          CHINA-003 UNIT1-RUNNING 
                          JAPAN-004 UNIT2-ONHOLD.,'  "TXT"  From Dual 
      ),
    cte AS (Select REPLACE(REPLACE(TXT, Chr(10), ''), CHR(9), '') "TXT" From tbl )
    
SELECT LISTAGG(
            CASE WHEN InStr(CASE WHEN InStr(SubStr(TXT, 1),' ') > 0 
                                THEN LTRIM(SubStr(  SubStr(TXT, 1), InStr(SubStr(TXT, 1), ' ')))
                            ELSE SubStr(TXT, 1)
                            END, '-') > 0
                THEN SubStr(CASE WHEN InStr(SubStr(TXT, 1),' ') > 0 
                                THEN LTRIM(SubStr(  SubStr(TXT, 1), InStr(SubStr(TXT, 1), ' ')))
                            ELSE SubStr(TXT, 1)
                            END, 1, 
                        InStr(CASE WHEN InStr(SubStr(TXT, 1),' ') > 0 
                                  THEN LTRIM(SubStr(  SubStr(TXT, 1), InStr(SubStr(TXT, 1), ' ')))
                              ELSE SubStr(TXT, 1)
                              END, '-') - 1 )
          ELSE  
                CASE WHEN InStr(SubStr(TXT, 1),' ') > 0 
                    THEN LTRIM(SubStr(  SubStr(TXT, 1), InStr(SubStr(TXT, 1), ' ')))
                ELSE SubStr(TXT, 1)
                END
          END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By 1) "TXT"
FROM  (  Select      l.LVL, 
                      LTRIM(REPLACE(SubStr( t.TXT, 
                                            CASE WHEN l.LVL = 1 THEN 1 ELSE Instr(t.TXT, '-', 1, (LVL-1)*2) END, 
                                            CASE WHEN l.LVL = 1 THEN Instr(t.TXT, '-', 1, 1) - 1 ELSE 9999999999 END
                                          ), ''))  "TXT"
          From        cte t
          Inner Join  (  Select LEVEL "LVL" From Dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CEIL((Select Length(TXT) - Length(Replace(TXT, Chr(10), '')) + 1 "LN" From tbl))  ) l ON(1 = 1) 
      )
```

The result should be the same ...