# Trim the data after special character

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want output as like below,

Current Output:

```
INDIA-001 UNIT1-RUNNING, AUSTRIA-002 UNIT2-RUNNING, CHINA-003 UNIT1-RUNNING , JAPAN-004 UNIT2-ONHOLD.,
```

Expected Output:

```
INDIA,AUSTRIA,CHINA,JAPAN
```

Comment: How is this different from your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75819596/trim-the-data-after-special-character-and-concatenate-row-data-into-column-with)? Looks like you can't express yourself and **explain** what you currently have (source data) and what you want to get (target data), along with **rules** that lead from A to B.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are surely cleverer ways of doing this, but the following works.

```
select listagg(trimmed_values,',') as trimmed_list
  from (select substr(trim(column_value),1,instr(trim(column_value),'-')-1) as trimmed_values
          from apex_string.split('INDIA-001 UNIT1-RUNNING, AUSTRIA-002 UNIT2-RUNNING, CHINA-003 UNIT1-RUNNING , JAPAN-004 UNIT2-ONHOLD.,',',')
         where trim(column_value) is not null);

TRIMMED_LIST
------------
INDIA,AUSTRIA,CHINA,JAPAN
```

Comment: Thanks it working as expected :) thanks for your quick support

Answer (score 0):

This method works by removing the parts you don't want.  The with just sets up test data.  The meat is in the select below that.  The REGEXP_REPLACE() matches a dash followed by one or more characters that are not a comma, when followed by a comma then a space or the end of the string.  If matched, it's replaced with a single comma (this removes the comma-space between the country names). To get rid of the last comma, wrap all that in the RTRIM().

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select 'INDIA-001 UNIT1-RUNNING, AUSTRIA-002 UNIT2-RUNNING, CHINA-003 UNIT1-RUNNING , JAPAN-004 UNIT2-ONHOLD.,'
  from dual
)
select rtrim(regexp_replace(str, '-[^,]+,( |$)', ','), ',') as country
from tbl;


COUNTRY                  
-------------------------
INDIA,AUSTRIA,CHINA,JAPAN
1 row selected
```

.